# Income personal tax reduction in Poland in SEZ

Tags: taxes, poland, tax-deductions

As i know there are SEZ (Special Economics Zones) in  Poland.
Is that true that personal income tax for employee works for IT company in SEZ Poland has not got 32% income tax but less 27-28%? I'm personally interested in Pomeranian SEZ.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: It's a hoax or a poor translation. SEZ affects corporate taxes, not income tax.